# How to use a fork library in Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-material, node-modules, fork, angular-library

I'm trying to migrate to Angular 15, but this library is blocking me:
https://github.com/merlosy/ngx-material-file-input

This issue is talked about here (update to Angular 15):
https://github.com/merlosy/ngx-material-file-input/issues/126

I tried in several ways to use the forked branch but none worked, so I first tried to make the current version work in Angular 14 in a clean new ng project to verify is anything related to my current project.

Note: I don't have experience working in a separate library so this is new for me.

So I forked the library the version 4.0.1:
https://github.com/daemons88/ngx-material-file-input

And try to use it in a clean project in angular 14, I tried installing it like this:

```
"material-file-input": "https://github.com/daemons88/ngx-material-file-input.git",
```

doing the postsinstall as is explained [here](https://blaipratdesaba.com/how-to-use-an-npm-node-module-that-has-been-forked-b7dd522fdd08), with the hope that install the library:

```
"postinstall": "cd ./node_modules/ngx-material-file-input && npm install && npm run build",
```

I tried other similar ways, but every time I have the same error in angular, cannot find the reference of the library in the project, for example in the app.module:

[image: import { MaterialFileInputModule } from 'ngx-material-file-input';]

How can I do this correctls, so I can continue upgrading the project to Angular 15?

Comment: Did you try this?
https://github.com/merlosy/ngx-material-file-input/issues/126#issuecomment-1370844042

Comment: No, I don't understand what she means. It would be something like 'ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15 --legacy-peer-deps', something like that?

Comment: Try this `npm i ngx-material-file-input --legacy-peer-deps`. Better remove the old one first

Answer (score -1):

Try running below command :

```
npm i ngx-material-file-input --save
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

That will install the npm version of ngx-material-file-input which is in angular 14 (tag 4.0.1), I want to install that same version but from the fork because my idea is after seeing that it already works this base in angular 14 from the fork, start updating it by hand or directly install the other forks that are already updated, but first I need to install it correctly from the 4.0.1 fork because if Is something wrong in the other forks or I the update wrong, I will not know if it is because I did something wrong or because I keep installing it in a wrong way.